# Code in Python for list replace "in place"

Tags: python, list

[image]

I am trying to do items switch using in-place in lists.

I can't understand why in the result its add " " alter a number,
instead of writing `[1,2,3,4]` (which that the result my teacher want) it gives me `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `return` is a statement, and doesn't need brackets, and `return None` doesn't need to be there. Python will automatically return `None` if no `return` statement is met.

Answer (score 3):

That's Python's representation of a list. It doesn't affect the data stored there, just how it's displayed, for readability.

Your teacher has simply missed out the spaces in the example given to you (which are there by convention, not necessity).

In short:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4] == [1, 2, 3, 4]
True
```

They are the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
print('[' + ','.join(str(i) for i in lst) + ']')
```

instead of

```
print(lst)
```